# Visual Studio 2017 : missing Events and Memory tabs in diagnostic tools

Tags: visual-studio-2017

With Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.8.3, in the diagnostic tools window, the tabs `Events` and `Memory Usage` are missing, only CPU Usage is visible :

**My Window** :

[image]

**How it should be** (captured from VS 2015 on the same machine) :

[image]

How to activate the tabs ?
Is it a Professional version restriction ? Did I miss a checkbox in the installation Wizard ? Or is it an installation bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was an install bug, the new 15.8.4 update resolved the issue.